# mysql python: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: mysql-python

i want to call a execute cursor but not much luck..
what is the problemt?

i think the problem is where i call `database.execute(sql, val)` is wrong some have..

this is my code

```
class database():
def connect(self):
    self.connection = mysql.connect (
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='12345678',
        database='datasheet'
    )
    self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

def execute(self, sql):
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)

def commit(self):
    self.connection.commit()

def add_to_user(self):
    sql = 'INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `time`, `system`, `ip`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
    val = (
        'sama',
        f'{getData().current_date()}'
        + ' - ' +
        f'{getData().current_time()}',
        f'{getData().current_os()}',
        f'{getData().current_ip()}'
    )
    database.execute(sql, val)
    database.commit


database().add_to_user()
```

and my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\WorkOuts\Back-End\Python\AutoKey\a.py", line 65, in <module>
    database().add_to_user()
  File "d:\WorkOuts\Back-End\Python\AutoKey\a.py", line 61, in add_to_user
    database.execute(sql, val)
  File "d:\WorkOuts\Back-End\Python\AutoKey\a.py", line 39, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your indentation as it is currently not valid python, and indentation is important in python. I'll assume all your functions are part of the database class, and the last line is not part of the class.

These 2 lines

```
database.execute(sql, val)
database.commit
```

should be using `self` instead of `database`. Also `database.commit` doesn't do anything - it references the function but doesn't call it as the `()` are missing.

Try replacing those 2 lines with:

```
self.execute(sql, val)
self.commit()
```

Also `execute` doesn't accept a `val` argument. It should probably be defined as

```
def execute(self, sql, vals):
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, vals)
```

You also need to call `connect()` before `add_to_user()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said but still got this error `AttributeError: 'database' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

Comment: That should be `self.execute` and `self.commit` (not `sql.` as previously given).